# Python - Group by a dataframe with a tolerance (with example)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a `groupBy` and giving a tolerance of +-1 seconds for example

Something like
`groupby(['Column1', 'Column2', 'EpochTimeInMs'])`

I tried to truncate it to minutes `(epoch_value - epoch_value%60000)` to group all values in the same minutes together

This works when the data frame is like

```
1 | 2 | 1659460439
1 | 2 | 1659460438
```

Result

```
1 | 2 | 1659460380
```

But for example if one value has 17:13:59 (in epoch) and the other 17:14:00 (in epoch) it will create 2 different rows like this

```
1 | 2 | 1659460439
1 | 2 | 1659460440
```

Result

```
1 | 2 | 1659460380
1 | 2 | 1659460440
```

Can you please point me in some way i can give it a tolerance or can pick those situations like in the `join_asof` since truncate to hours will be such a big interval it will not work?

Something like

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Joseph'], 'Weight': ['60', '75', '75'], 'RegisterTime': ['1659460439', '1659460439', '1659460440']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

and would come something like

Tom    | 60 | 1659460380
Joseph | 75 | 1659460380

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432153/group-nearby-dates

Comment: thanks i can start from there, in this case i would just want to group the rows in order to only consider output 1 row instead of 2 
This means I don't need to make any change in the data besides the epoch time being rounded down or up to all the entries in that 1 second range for example